# Count sheets if specific cell equals string

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to count each sheet for which cell A1 = "next" then store that number as a variable. Then set cell A2 on current sheet equal to that variable. Here is what I have:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

i = 0
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If range("A1").value = "next"
i = i + 1
End If
Activesheet.Range("a2").Value = i
Next ws
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell vba on which sheet Range("A1") belongs:

```
If ws.range("A1").value = "next" Then
```

So:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
i = 0
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.range("A1").value = "next"
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Activesheet.Range("A2").Value = i
Next ws
```

Comment: Isn't A2 supposed to be equal to the count?

Comment: was missing the "ws". Thank you!

Comment: @mooseman the original code, before the updates had it in A1.  But I have changed it.

Comment: Scott, how would I be able to select a range and delete it with the "i" variable?  I want to delete row 6 and "i" rows beneath it. `Rows("6:6+i").Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: @carter that is a new question, usually, but `ActiveSheet.Rows(6).Resize(i).Delete`

Comment: Thanks again Scott